# How to configure css output file webpack 5 vue.js 3?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I'm trying to configure vue.js webpack for development mode. I have a separate folder in root directory named "styles" where I keep all my scss and include main.scss to main.js. I want to have the separate css file in the dist folder.

There is my **vue.config.js**:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: config => {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
            return {
                plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                    filename: '[name].css',
                    chunkFilename:'[name].css'
                })],
                module: {
                    rules: [
                        {
                            test: /\.css$/,
                            use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
                        }
                    ]
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Screen Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWQj6.png)

Comment: Please share your complete code for Webpack